# Inequality connected to Lagrange's interpolation formula

Tags: inequality, lagrange-interpolation

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and 
$$
0 < x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < \dots < x_n < y_n.
$$
Show that
$$
a_{ij} := \sum_{k=1}^n \Big( \prod_{l\neq k} \frac{y_l^2-x_k^2}{x_l^2-x_k^2}\Big) \frac{y_k^2-x_k^2}{x_k (y_i^2-x_k^2)(y_j^2-x_k^2)} > 0 \qquad \text{ for all } i,j = 1,\dots, n.
$$

The case $i=j$ is simple: $y_l^2 - x_k^2$ and $x_l^2-x_k^2$ have the same sign for all $k,l = 1, \dots, n.$
Since also $y_k^2 > x_k^2$ for all $k=1,\dots,n,$ every summand is positive.

For $i \neq j$, some summands are negative:
The problem is symmetric, so we may assume $i > j.$
Then $(y_i^2 - x_k^2)(y_j^2-x_k^2) < 0$ if and only if $j < k \le i.$
These negative summands must be offset by the other, positive ones. 
How can I show that?

I know this is a very specific question. I am grateful for any idea how to approach this; or a reference to similar problems.

> 

My approach so far was to apply Lagrange's interpolation formula.
Define 
$$
p(x) := \frac12\prod_{l=1}^n (x_l-x) \prod_{k=1}^n (x_l+x) = \frac12\prod_{k=1}^n (x_l^2 - x^2).
$$
This is a polynomial of degree $2n$, and it holds that
$$
p'(x_k) = - x_k \prod_{l \neq k} (x_l^2-x_k^2) \qquad \text{ and } \qquad p'(-x_k) =  x_k \prod_{l \neq k} (x_l^2 - x_k^2)
$$
for $k = 1, \dots, n.$
Since
$$
\frac1{(y_i^2-x_k^2)(y_j^2-x_k^2)} = \frac1{y_i^2-y_j^2} \Big( \frac1{y_i^2-x_k^2} - \frac1{y_j^2 - x_k^2}\Big),
$$
we may write
$$
a_{ij} = \frac1{y_i^2 - y_j^2}\Big( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_i(-x_k)}{p'(-x_k)(y_i+x_k)} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_j(-x_k)}{p'(-x_k)(y_j+x_k)}\Big) = \frac1{y_i^2 - y_j^2}\Big( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_i(x_k)}{p'(x_k)(y_i-x_k)} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_j(x_k)}{p'(x_k)(y_j-x_k)}\Big) 
$$
with
$$
f_m(x) := -\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{y_m+x} \prod_{l=1}^n (y_l^2-x^2), \qquad m \in \{i,j\}.
$$
Unfortunately, $f_i$ and $f_j$ are not polynomials.